# In my build system, critical unversioned files are being deleted

Tags: svn, jenkins

In Jenkins, unversioned files like `build.properties` are being deleted when the build is triggered. Because of this the build fails. How can this be prevented?

Comment: How are unversioned files getting into your Jenkins workspace in the first place?

Comment: I am not sure. I am just looking into the build system.

Comment: I'm very certain it's either the jenkins svn plugin or some aspect of the build script that is removing the unversioned files.

Answer (score 3):

Subversion does not even provide an option for removing unversioned files.  So Subversion is not doing this.

The Jenkins plugin for SVN has an option for the Checkout strategy: "Emulate clean checkout by first deleting unversioned/ignored files, then 'svn update'"

It sounds like you must be using that option.  Check your Jenkins job configuration and use a different option, such as "Use 'svn update' as much as possible"

Comment: FYI 1.9.0 will probably include such an option.  But Mark's right that it doesn't exist in a released version yet.  Right now trunk has a `--remove-unversioned` option to the `cleanup` command.  That may change between now and when 1.9.0 finally releases.

Answer (score 3):

Though @Mark Phippards [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21124569/505191) will likely get you past your immediate issue, the real problem is requiring unversioned files to make your build work.  It sounds like it's an ant build? I would recommend having a hierarchical import of properties files.

Properties in ant are immutable, so you can load multiple properties files - the first one wins and it cannot be changed. Importing a non-versioned properties file first gives the dev team a convenient mechanism to set properties in a mostly persistent manner on their workstation.

1. Check in `build.properties` to the svn project
2. in `build.xml` import `user.properties` *above* `build.properties`
3. Add `users.properties` to `svn:ignore` so it will never get checked in.

In your jenkins build you can set any properties that need to be set or overridden.

The main point is - your project should build right after check out, you shouldn't need to create property (or any other non-versioned) files.